# Don't understand TypeScript function signature with weird object type as param

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following function signature:

```
(JSX attribute) onScroll: ({ scrollOffset, scrollUpdateWasRequested }: {
    scrollDirection: string;
    scrollOffset: number;
    scrollUpdateWasRequested: boolean;
}) => void
```

I just can't wrap my head around it. What I read is "onScroll is a function that returns nothing (void) and takes weird object-type-mix as param. Could somebody explaind this weird object-type-mix to me?

Function signature is from onScroll prop of react-virtualitzed AutoSizer btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's using [parameter destructuring assignment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#parameter-destructuring).  You can write a function like this in JavaScript:

```
function foo({ x, y }) {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase(), y.toFixed(2));
}
foo({ x: "hello", y: Math.PI }) // HELLO, 3.14
```

This [unpacks the (anonymous) parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) into `x` and `y` variables inside the function body.  TypeScript allows you to strongly type this by treating `{ x, y }` as the name of the parameter which you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) like a regular named parameter:

```
function foo({ x, y }: { x: string, y: number }) {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase(), y.toFixed(2));
}
```

Also note that you are not required to unpack every property in the passed-in parameter.  If for some reason you wanted to force callers to include a property in the parameter that you don't use, you can still do it by giving the annotated type that property:

```
function bar({ x, y }: { x: string, y: number, z: boolean }) {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase(), y.toFixed(2));
}
bar({ x: "hello", y: Math.PI, z: true }) // HELLO, 3.14
```

So `bar()` needs a parameter with `x`, `y`, and `z` properties of particular types, but the function implementation doesn't actually care about `z`.

---

Therefore your `onScroll` function is equivalent to the following declaration:

```
declare const onScroll: (param: OnScrollParam) => void
type OnScrollParam = {
    scrollDirection: string;
    scrollOffset: number;
    scrollUpdateWasRequested: boolean;
}
```

Meaning that `onScroll()` takes a single parameter of type `OnScrollParam`, which requires that `scrollDirection` property, despite the fact that apparently the implementation doesn't use it:

```
onScroll({
    scrollDirection: "",
    scrollOffset: 1,
    scrollUpdateWasRequested: false
}); // okay

onScroll({
    scrollOffset: 1,
    scrollUpdateWasRequested: false
}); // error! Property 'scrollDirection' is missing
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2&ssl=8&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBRAHuGAbZBvAsAFBIlIBmArsPAC4CWA9sOQwwBS5JoA0SAnkgC+ALiSc0oqDQBOdYAHNefUcApgARhGm9BASjFFSRpPCZQGOAHRYG8tmks0GAVRgwtAYRBQIbXUscGADE6NAgAEzYAJl1dAG5DUkFEkjJWDi5RACIACwgsGyylUQBZEBocywAFAEkhfQB6BqQACRQAGXaAeV4AZksARgAWIlHiUkpqeiYkdRBpDJ5+IVFxSRk5RX4VNU1tJAAvUXVWHBBmPQNx4xMzCwhrW3tA13dpLx8-AKcQsMiY+IpIRAuYLNZIXL5QrFJBlCrVGq8I5IGQUZCXJqtDrdPqDEaEMbJAmEUCQWAIZBdWTyK5GcIQeBYebIUzAKRIJgAZXg0gsWFEGSgPL5XTIZB8NF4Qt5BVc4XKEAA6t4AEoQACOaKkERWtJuSGlfIAInRpAzpsB1rIFAlrsZDQVReKIDQdhotLb9QbhbKYPKaErVRqtQHwsdThBzp6kvoALwAPiQADcGHRwmMjFyfVgOECjA6sCazbRGJaIUU86QC06JaIBtxKyQC3KFcqoGrNdBQ6IyCAsD4gXo4khMQwANYgPhjIFZmU5gh2-PZmsuusNxdV7MtgNtjshiI9vsDu1DkfNLS86QAQiQVV5bxoAgA5AWi+bS0+kHQoEgwN+oJsSCEmMpLQHAiCoJqdBJlcGakPSjLMrcbI0BywDcnOApwNI4CiF06HZlU8zgHGiYpmmQKPu4SD4RhfJEThYBILGeo3K+prvkwVqbNGbHLmKtZIKo7rSLx9pbn6rZBp22phrMEZRoOcEkLOfK5huTbZm+JZceW65etWAmrkg9aNt6c7boG7bBl2B7kEeECDvEZ4chOU7EpmBFzupBn8c6romfp+rNpJO7Sfucm9v2jkns5mIXgw163veWiPkgL5aRxOnAJ+36-v+gHAYQQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I know what the code does I'm wondering if writing code that way is desirable in TypeScript (especially in this specific situation where the type definition has additional unused fields). I mean wouldn't it be more straight forward to do

onScroll(scrollOffset: number, scrollUpdateWasRequested: boolean)

and then pass the fields of the object holding the data instead of the whole object?
Also from a "need-to-know" principle point of view.